# tricky injectivity proof

Tags: functions

let A= {3,4,p} and B={0,1,s}. Define f: A-->B such that f(3)=0 and f(4)=1 and f(p)=s Prove that f is injective.

Right. If we apply the usual trick we have, let a,b be in A and assume f(a)=f(b). But now we are stuck? tricky isn't it?

Comment: Not really.  Assuming that $s\neq 0,1$ and $p\neq 3,4$ then $f(3)\neq f(4)$, $f(3)\neq f(p)$ and $f(4)\neq f(p)$ so the function is indeed injective.

Comment: In fact, it is bijective. Isn't this....obvious?

Comment: wat do you mean obvious? if its so obvious then wheres the proof?

Comment: what do you mean s =/= 0,1? s is an element of B. It is just as valid as the element 0 or 1.

Comment: I didn't say it was invalid...I'm just not sure what it would mean to write $\{0,1,0\}$ say.  You gave no information at all about what $s$ was, so I was trying to exclude a possibly degenerate case.

Comment: well the point of my question is that this function is defined in such a way that it does not yield to the usual trick we are taught to prove injectivity. Your method works but you have to go through each pair a,b from the domain.

Comment: so is that the only way?

Comment: Your function is defined by a list of values!  To show any desired property of it, you have to go through the list.  By the way, I would say this is the usual method.  Of course if you have a situation where a formula makes sense then you can exploit the formula.  But sometimes a list is just a list.

Comment: so does your method use the fact that f(a)=f(b) implies a=b but the premise is never true so we are done

Comment: The method is: "look at all pairs with $a\neq b$ and comfirm, case by case, that $f(a)\neq f(b)$".

Answer (score 2):

Each value in $B$ is taken exactly once via $f$. In particular, $f$ is injective.

Comment: thats what is required to be shown.